# Does O(f(n)) + Ω(g(n)) equal Ω(f(n)) + O(g(n))?

Tags: big-o, computer-science

Is the following equation true? :

> O(f(n)) + Ω(g(n)) = Ω(f(n)) + O(g(n))

I know that Big O means no better than (function), and Big Omega means no worse than (function). But I don't know if that makes the above statement true or false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(n) = n, g(n)= 2^n$

$t(n) = 2n$ is in second set, because $n = Ω(f(n))$ and $n = O(g(n))$, but not in the first

Comment: So I let t(n) to be t(n) = t1(n) + t2(n)
t1(n) = n, t2(n)=n 
t1(n)∈ Ω(f(n)) , t2(n)∈O(g(n)) and that is right.
in the other hand(the other side)
t1(n)∈O(f(n)) , t2(n) ∉ Ω(g(n))

Answer (score 1):

We have three general cases (for increasing functions):

- **Case 1:** f(n) ∈ o(g(n)) (note the "little-oh").

  In this case, O(f(n)) ⊂ O(g(n)) and Ω(g(n)) ⊂ Ω(f(n)). Hence, O(f(n)) + Ω(g(n)) is a proper subset of O(g(n)) + Ω(f(n)).

  For example, if f(n) = n and g(n) = n<sup>3</sup>, then n<sup>2</sup> is in Ω(f(n)) + O(g(n)), but it is not in O(f(n)) + Ω(g(n)).
- **Case 2:** f(n) ∈ Θ(g(n))

  In this case, O(f(n)) = O(g(n)) and Ω(g(n)) = Ω(g(n)), so the two sets are equal.
- **Case 3:** f(n) ∈ ω(g(n))

  This case is equivalent to case 1, just with *f* and *g* flipped. So by symmetry, we have that O(f(n)) + Ω(g(n)) is a proper *superset* of O(g(n)) + Ω(f(n)).

In sum, these two sets are not equal in general.

Comment: It's not true that there are only 3 cases. Suppose f(n) = 1 if n is odd and 2^n otherwise, g(n)=n^2. It doesn't change the main idea of the answer which sentense starting from "for example"

Comment: @RiaD Thanks. I've added "for increasing functions" to resolve the issue‌ :>